# "Object has no attribute" in Blender Game Engine

Tags: python, scripting

i have a problem with this code,i want to create a custom mouse cursor in bge
i use blender 2.77
but i have something wrong like this

[image: phyton error, object has not have a atrribute]
[image: like this]

can't anyone can solve this code?

Answer (score -1):

`cont.sensors["mouse"]` instead of `cont.sensor["mouse"]`